# What happend to the tension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, equilibrium

[image: question (iii)]If crane with uniform arm raised by shortening cable,what is the effect to the tension of the cable?I know the tension will increase but what cause? Bcs of increasing in angle?Or got thing with torque?How to explain it? What formula to proof it. Bcs i cant find the suitable formula to proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the tension decreases because as you lift the crane the lever arm of the tension increases in order to balance the opposite torque due to the crane's weight.